# Swift Async/Await for C Callbacks

Tags: c, swift, async-await

I am trying to convert some code from objective-c to swift and along with that use async/await as much as possible.

This code leverages a C library that uses callbacks with a void* context. There are parts of our code where we need to "wait" until the callback is completed. This can often be 2 different callbacks for success or failure.

Below is an example of the code

```
class Test
{
    var sessionStarted: Bool = false
    let sessionSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    // We need the session to be available once this function returns
    func startSession() throws
    {
        guard !sessionStarted else {
            print("Session already started")
            return
        }

        let callback: KMSessionEventCallback = { inSession, inEvent, inContext in
            guard let session = inSession, let context = inContext else { return }

            let testContext: Test = Unmanaged<Test>.fromOpaque(context).takeUnretainedValue()
            testContext.handleSessionUpdate(session: session, event: inEvent)
        }

        let result = KMSessionAttach("SessionTest", &callback, Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        if result != KM_SUCCESS {
            print("Failed to attach session")
        }

        // Currently uses a semaphore to wait. =(
        let dispatchResult = self.sessionSemaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(30))
        if dispatchResult == .timedOut {
            print("Waited 30 seconds and never attached session")
        }
    }

    private func handleSessionUpdate(session: KMSession, event: KMSessionEvent)
    {
        switch event
        {
        case KM_SESSION_ATTACHED:
            self.sessionStarted = true
        case KM_SESSION_TERMINATED:
            fallthrough
        case KM_SESSION_FAILED:
            fallthrough
        case KM_SESSION_DETACHED:
            self.sessionStarted = false
        default:
            print("Unknown State")
        }

        self.sessionSemaphore.signal()
    }
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how to use continuations here because I cannot capture any context within these C callbacks.

Comment: For these kinds of APIs, I would suggest writing a wrapper which takes a callback _closure_ as a param, calls the wrapped function (`KMSessionAttach`) passing the closure as the context, with a `@convention(c)` callback which casts the `context` back into the same closure type, and calls it. That way, it's a regular ol' closure callback based API, as far as the rest of your code is concerns, which can capture values like any other. This does a nice job of separating concerns (C-related plumbing, vs actual callback business logic)

Comment: To contrast, with the code you currently have, your piping `self` along as the context. "I am struggling to figure out how to use continuations here because I cannot capture any context within these C callbacks." You actually can: you have access to any fields available on `self`. Presumably you _could_ store your continuation as a property on `self`, and read it from your callback. You shouldn't do that though, because it'll clutter your object and complicate its lifecycle. By passing a closure instead, you can capture things as normal, and still call methods on `self` if you so wish.